# Output All Rows of a File Whose 3rd and 4th Line are Within a Certain Range of the 3rd and 4th Columns of Another File

Tags: sorting, range, filtering

I am looking for help with filtering through a few thousand star brightnesses I have on text files. I have two text files (both of the same star field, just different filters), each file has four columns:

---

Column 1 - Brightness  |
Column 2 - Uncertainty  |
Column 3 - X coordinate  |
Column 4 - Y coordinate  |

---

The x and y coordinates for the stars in each filter can be slightly off though... So I am looking to use a code similar to something like:`awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$3$4]++;next};c[$3$4]' file1 file2 > output.txt` but that can find matches for the 3rd and 4th columns within 1.5 units between the two images.

---

Essentially, I am looking for a way to compare two columns and print the row if it is within the +/- 1.5 range of the other file's columns. Any ideas would be hugely appreciated. Thank you.